Was Eric Morecambe playing all the right notes?
There's a famous moment when André Previn appears on the Morecambe and Wise show.



"You're playing all the wrong notes."
"I'm playing all the right notes, but not necessarily in the right order."
Was he?

He was playing all the wrong notes of Grieg's Piano Concerto.
He was playing all the right notes of Grieg's Piano Concerto but in the wrong order.


I think Valorum has explained why the joke works for the whole audience, even those who don't know the concerto. Musically, it sounds like Morecambe was playing one of the themes from later in the concerto, but playing it in a different mode and with a different rhythm and texture from the original. The combined effects of the musical changes enhances the humor for anyone familiar with the music.

There are only eighty-eight notes on a keyboard. It would be hard for him to play any complex tune, in this instance a jaunty version of the Morecambe and Wise theme song, without hitting all of the same notes, albeit not necessarily in the same order, which is the essence of his joke.
It seems unlikely (in the extreme) that he has intentionally deconstructed the concerto to ensure that the same notes are used, and in the same quantities. Such a 'musical anagram'  would be a feat of intellectual virtuosity, akin to writing a poem using only the exact letters as a Shakespearean sonnet, but I can't imagine the results would be worthwhile.
